# Who/what decides about which sites can post be migrated to?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231261/ubuntu-server-monitor-goes-to-sleep-in-10-minutes), and since it asks about something Ubuntu-specific, I thought about flagging it for migration. However, I've only found SO and Meta links. What should I do if I want to indicate that this should, in my opinion, be migrated to Ubuntu SE?

Comment: My bad, didn't see this.

tl;dr : if enough questions are moved to SE site, the option will appear.

Comment: Asking the mod in a flag nicely. Don't use it too often. It is influenced highly by intra-SE relations and having 200+ on around 20 sites I would say: 1) its deep politics exist, 2) it is nearly unknown, 3) but doesn't seem logical. If you don't understand why is it, it is often not because of the mods, but because powers over them. The probable final reason is that SO (with around 10 mods) makes around the same visit number as the whole SE (with around 300 mods).